# plot data points where color is given by a range of values

Tags: r, plot

I have the following matrix

```
> mdat <- matrix(c(0.25,0.45,0.3, 0.75,0.15,0.62,0.40,0.90,1, 0.45,0.15,0), nrow = 4, ncol = +3, byrow = TRUE)
> mdat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.25 0.45 0.30
[2,] 0.75 0.15 0.62
[3,] 0.40 0.90 1.00
[4,] 0.45 0.15 0.00
```

I need  to plot it with pch = 22 (squares) but the squares should be colored according to the following:
red if data point in (0.0, 0.25)
orange if data point in (0.26,0.50)
blue if data point in (0.51, 0.75)
green if data point in (0.76, 1.00)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `findInterval` to generate an index used to pick the colors from a vector of color values:

```
plot(rep(1:4, 3), mdat, pch=22, 
                   col=c("red","orange","blue")[findInterval(mdat, c(0,.25,.5,.75))])
```